# SSIS Package with SharePoint Doesn't Execute In Agent Job (Fine when ran manually from SSIS Store)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2010

So I've created a neat SSIS package which essentially reads a SharePoint 2010 list, moves the data into a 'Delete' list, (thus deleting the contents), then populates the list with fresh data pulled from a SQL Database.

It works in Visual Studio just fine, it works if I'm logged into Integration Services and run the package manually fine, but when I place it into a SQL job I get nothing. 
 At first I thought maybe it was that I didn't install the SharePoint destination connection manager thing on the server, so I did, only quickly then realizing that if that was the cause, running the package manually from SSIS would have failed.

Then I figured it was the account it was being executed under (SSIS Service Account), so I created a proxy (SharePoint Admin) and added the credential, still no go. Then I added my own credentials, just to be sure, and still no go. Just to be super sure, I also added the SQL Agent account as a SharePoint Site Collection Administrator, which means the account now runs the package fine by right clicking on the package from Integration Services, but put it into a SQL Agent Job as a step, no love.

The job doesn't fail either, it just sits there spinning and spinning. I'm stumped. I've tried turning on logging as far as the options allow me under the advanced tab on the job step, but as the job doesn't fail, nothing is logged.

There's no question that the job can be run, using either my account or the SQL Agent account, but place it into a SQL job, nothing! I'm going crazy here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that that your SQL Agent account MUST be an SA on the server in order for it to be able to run SSIS packages as part of a job step when the 'Bulk Insert' task type is employed by the package...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239.aspx

N03L